# Using "not only but also"

Tags: grammar

Here is a question I got:
[image]

Will the correct answer be

"Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, but also our total dedication."

or

"Earth Day deserves not only a commemoration, but also our total dedication."?

Comment: Parallelism is best maintained by "Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, it also deserves our total dedication." or "Earth Day deserves not only a commemoration, but also our total dedication."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you so much for replying! The teacher said the second is correct, perhaps that's why.  I have just one more question, but I'm not able to post it because of the timer. Can you please [come on the site's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) so I can ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Earth Day deserves not only a commemoration, but also our total dedication."

This is correct here, since is perfectly maintains the parallelism.  However, you have to remove the comma.

> "Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, but also our total dedication."

This breaks the parallelism, so it is incorrect.  A better alternative would be "Not only does Earth Day deserve a commemoration, it deserves our total dedication".

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me with one more question?

Comment: Sure!  Where did you post it?

Comment: Here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage The last few messages

Comment: @Rick I have answered.  Alternatively you could post it as a question

Comment: I would like to know the reasons for downvoting my answer

Comment: _Not only/but also_ is a coordinating conjuntion. If it only joins two noun phrases, then there is no comma.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected that

Comment: is it better now